# jQuery's `mouseout` conflicting with password manager

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to create a sign-in pop-in. My intent is that when you hover over the user icon the pop-in pops in. When the mouse leaves the pop-in, it should disapear.

Everything works fine except when I turn on a password manager like dashlane. It creates an area within the pop-in with buttons offering to auto-complete the sign-in form. When I hover over this area, jQuery's mouseout event gets triggered, and closes the pop in.

HTML:

```
<nav>
  ...
  <div class='user-icon'>
    <div class='pop-in'>
      <form ...>
        <input type='email' />
        <input type='password' />
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

JS:

```
$('.pop-in').mouseleave(function() {
  closePopIn()
})
```

Comment: That's an issue with most of this chrome extensions. Not only dashlane but lastpass, form-fillers, etc. I don't think you should consider this as a stoppage to your work. You should ignore them because chrome extensions run in background and can change DOM elements.

Comment: It could be quite hard to avoid this kind of an action, since Dashlane itself causes it and you can't edit the way it functions. I do however recommend that you toggle the login screen by mouseover, but do leave it open even if mouseout. It provides better usage for mobile devices as well if you're planning to implement this on a responsive design service (of course you must then provide an alternative for mouseover as well).